# How can I check a string for two letters or more?

Tags: python, string, filter, digits, letter

I am pulling data from a table that changes often using Python - and the method I am using is not ideal. What I would like to have is a method to pull all strings that contain only one letter and leave out anything that is 2 or more.

An example of data I might get:

```
115
19A6
HYS8
568
```

In this example, I would like to pull 115, 19A6, and 568.

Currently I am using the `isdigit()` method to determine if it is a digit and this filters out all numbers with one letter, which works for some purposes, but is less than ideal.

Comment: Please provide reproducible example, including the code you tried so far.

Comment: Have you tried regular expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an excellent case for regular expressions (regex), which is available as the built-in [`re` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

The code below follows the logic:

- Define the dataset. Two examples have been added to show that a string containing two alpha-characters is rejected.
- Compile a character pattern to be matched. In this case, zero or more digits, followed by zero or one upper case letter, ending with zero of more digits.
- Use the [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function to detect matches in the data list and output as a list.

For example:

```
import re

data = ['115', '19A6', 'HYS8', '568', 'H', 'HI']
rexp = re.compile('^\d*[A-Z]{0,1}\d*$')
result = list(filter(rexp.match, data))

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['115', '19A6', '568', 'H']
```

Comment: Yet, in my eyes the most elegant solution. Not sure about runtime (someone could test that ;D), but it get's my upvote for the nice regex as well as the didactic format the answer is put in! +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string_list = ["115", "19A6", "HYS8", "568"]
output_list = []

for item in string_list: # goes through the string list
    letter_counter = 0 
    for letter in item: # goes through the letters of one string
        if not letter.isdigit(): # checks if the letter is a digt
            letter_counter += 1
    if letter_counter < 2: # if the string has more then 1 letter it wont be in output list
        output_list.append(item)

print(output_list)
```

Output:

```
['115', '19A6', '568']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner with a regular expression:

```
import re

data = ["115", "19A6", "HYS8", "568"]
out = [string for string in data if len(re.sub("\d", "", string))<2]
print(out)
```

Output:

```
['115', '19A6', '568']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, without `re` using `str.maketrans`/`str.translate`:

```py
lst = ["115", "19A6", "HYS8", "568"]

d = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(map(str, range(10)), ""))

out = [i for i in lst if len(i.translate(d)) < 2]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
['115', '19A6', '568']
```

Answer (score 0):

````
z=False
a = str(a)
for I in range(len(a)):
    if a[I].isdigit():
        z = True
        break
    else:
        z="no digit"
print(z)```
````

Comment: Please, consider adding some explanation to your, otherwise code-only, answer :)